# Is it possible to take DynamoDB Tables in one go based on a Tag Value?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, backup, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-local

Is it possible to take DynamoDB Tables in one go based on a Tag Value ?

I have about 30 tables that needs to be backedup . I have created a Tag called " Backup " and assigned a value " daily " . Is it possible to take a backup of all these tables in one-go based on the Tag-Value ?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to write something custom to do a call to get all of the tables with this tag and then for each in the list, run the on-demand backup API call.

Though I have to ask, why not enable [continuous backups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/PointInTimeRecovery.html) on these tables and not worry about backups being done? Then you get point in time recovery to any second in the last 35 days.